# Bottle web framework: any way to run a console/shell and get it to work with Werkzeug?

Tags: bottle, werkzeug

I searched but couldn't find an easy way to run a console or shell akin to Django's `manage.py shell` or Rail's `rails console`

Since I just started using Bottle for an existing project, I just wanted to play around with the existing models and managers in the console. The closest I came up with was using ipdb's set_trace() and go from there, but that's not ideal by any means.

Also, I tried integrating Bottle with Werkzeug, but when I follow the instructions:

```
import bottle
app = bottle.Bottle()
werkzeug = bottle.ext.werkzeug.Plugin()
app.install(werkzeug)
```

I get the following traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mysite.py", line 62, in <module>
werkzeug = bottle.ext.werkzeug.Plugin()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'werkzeug'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding importing bottle.ext.werkzeug by adding this at the beginning of your source:

```
import bottle.ext.werkzeug
```